# Trace Recursive Algorithms with a pass by reference argument

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

The passed by reference argument is a shared item between caller and callee.
Is this item in sharing for recursive calls of a function ?

Suppose this merge sort algorithm:

```
MergeSort(ref int[]S)
{
    .
    .
    .
    MergeSort(ref S1);
    MergeSort(ref S2);
    Merge(S1,S2,S);
}
```

By tracing algorithm for S={2,3,1,0} , we have :

```
                2,3,0,1
        2,3                 1,0
      2     3             1     0
```

At the end of algorithm ,compiler will do a merge into S in second level of tree, that merges(0,1) and (2,3) and creates (0,1,2,3).

We have just a one S array that is shared , How the compiler merge 2 of S arrays and merged them ?
So S is not sharing??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Excuse me !the algorithm tracing is more important for me,I want that the C Family Programmers give me an idea .

Comment: @PasJ: But the three different languages handle parameters somewhat differently. For example, Java doesn't *have* pass-by-reference at all. The question is meaningless without picking a specific language and ideally giving more complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **object** is passed by reference **BUT** in every recursive call, the **variable** `S` points [refers] to a different object. Thus, every `merge()` is actually preformed on a different object.

Comment: Which language are you talking about? Because in C# at least (which the sample looks most like) objects can't be passed by reference: *variables* can be passed by reference, or *references* can be passed by value.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am not refering to C#, but to java and C++. I know java doesn't have pass by reference mechanism, but I think the OP means by 'pass by reference': pass a reference to the original object [reference passed by value]

Comment: Given that "pass by reference" and "pass reference by value" *are* distinct things, using one term to describe both merely adds confusion instead of insight IMO.